# How to get source and target branch in TeamCity build?

Tags: git, build, teamcity

I'm wonder is there any way to extract source and target branch during TeamCity PullRequest build (my git server is bitbucket). I would like to use those information in my build script.

Comment: When you attach a VCS root to builds, it automatically adds some parameters to builds. If you go to a previous build that was successful and view the build parameters, there should be some git variables there. You could also run some git commands in a build step to extract those variables.

Comment: I found that those variables are avaliable but from 2019.2 - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html#PullRequests-Predefinedbuildparametersforpullrequests

Comment: What version are you using? The best option may then to be write a script and extract this information from some git commands.
Is the build being fired off from a web hook?

Comment: I finally got this from bitbucket rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that those variables are available but from 2019.2

[TeamcityDocs:](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html#Predefined+build+parameters+for+pull+requests)

```
teamcity.pullRequest.number //pull request number
teamcity.pullRequest.title //pull request title
teamcity.pullRequest.source.branch //VCS name of the source branch; provided only if the source repository is the same as the target one
teamcity.pullRequest.target.branch //VCS name of the target branch
```